# PyQt5 input text can't be executed as code in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: pyqt5

I have a QMainWindow which contains a QPlainTextEdit and a button with clicked even connected. When user finishes text input and press the button, I just want to execute user input for example "1+1". I should get "2", but it is "1+1". Very appreciated for your reply, thanks!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, \
    QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPlainTextEdit, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        l_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.edit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.edit.setFixedSize(400, 300)
        self.edit1 = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.edit1.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Test')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.press)
        l_layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        l_layout.addWidget(self.edit1)
        l_layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        dummy_widget = QWidget()
        dummy_widget.setLayout(l_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(dummy_widget)

    def press(self):
        text = self.edit.toPlainText()
        try:
            code = """print(text)"""
            exec(code)
        except Exception as e:
            print('not ok!')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You should implement expression evaluator, something like infix to postfix then evaluate.

Comment: I can't understand. Sorry. Would you pls tell me how to correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [evaluate](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/eval.html) the input text and then print it, like so:

```py
 def press(self):
        text = self.edit.toPlainText()
        try:
            print(eval(text))
        except Exception as e:
            print('not ok!')
```

Pay attention, because `eval()` use can lead to security issues (people executing python code on your app). Make sure your input is sanitized.

Comment: Oh my God! got it! so amazing! By the way, what is eval(text)? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain :). `eval(text)` is a function that execute the text you put in it as code (This is why you should be careful on using it). You can find extra info on the link i put in the Answer.